SecurityError: Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL
I am working on a bank project on the Cordova framework. As per Apple's recent policy, I have built the bundle from Xcode 15.4 and iOS runtime 17+.
My app worked fine when I used Xcode 14.2 and runtime version 16.2. But after upgrading to the latest version, I am facing the below error.

SecurityError: Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL.  Only differences in query and fragment are allowed for file: URLs.

using
cordova-ios@3.6.3
jquery v3.6.0
jquery-mobile 1.5.0

I tried $pushEnableState = false but not working.
Please suggest any other solution. FYI I can't go for the Cordova-IOS version update instead I need a solution on the same version i.e. 3.6.3.
Thanks in Advance.

Please provide a [mcve].

This solution worked for me.
Disabled pushEnableState in index.html before invoking jQuery js file. Here is the snippet.
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
      /* Disable pushState to avoid replaceState issues */
      $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js'>
</script>

